# Is it possible to program a RFID tag like a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, rfid, protocol

I am working on an RFID project. I want to be able to send specific messages between the reader and the tag or maybe perform my own protocols on it. Is there a type of tag that I can provide some sort of firmware for? (be able to program it like a microcontroller) Or do I have to design my own layout for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the tag. Some tags are programmable in some restricted sense that is defined by the manufacturer, using a kind of scripting language that allows certain operations to be performed and data to be stored locally on the tag.

But, "like a microcontroller", implying that you have full access to the "bare metal" hardware? No.

Comment: Can you give please give me an example of such tags?

Comment: I'm afraid not. All I have is a vague recollection of reading about them in a journal of some sort. It may even have been a research project that has not yet been commercialized.